# A problem with FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following

```
With[{p2 = 0.75}, FindRoot[1/(64 (p1 - p2)^2 (-(-1 + p2) p2)^(
 3/2) (-1 + p1 + p2)^2) (1 - p1) p1 (-128 (-(-1 + p1) p1)^(3/2) (-1 + p2)^2 p2^2 + (384 (-1 + p1)^3 p1^3)/Sqrt[1/(p2 - p2^2)] + 128 Sqrt[-(-1 + p1) p1] (-1 + p2)^3 p2^3 (-3 + 2 Sqrt[((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1)]) + 128 Sqrt[1/(p1 - p1^2)] (3 (-1 + p1) p1 (-1 + p2)^3 p2^3 - (-1 + p2)^4 p2^4 + (2 (-(-1 + p2) p2)^(7/2))/Sqrt[1/(p1 - p1^2)] + ((-1 + p2)^4 p2^4)/(((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1))^(3/2) + 3 (-1 + p1)^4 p1^4 Sqrt[((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1)] - 6 (-1 + p1)^4 p1^4 (((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1))^(3/2)) + 4 (1 - p1) p1 (-128 (-(-1 + p2) p2)^(5/2) - 96/(1/(p2 - p2^2))^(5/2)) + 256 (-1 + p1)^2 p1^2 ((-(-1 + p2) p2)^(3/2) + 3/(1/(p2 - p2^2))^(3/2))) == 0, {p1, 0.5}]]
```

which produces the solution

```
{p1 -> 0.882142}
```

Now, I try to generate a series of such solution. I start by creating the equation

```
eqn = 1/(64 (p1 - p2)^2 (-(-1 + p2) p2)^(3/2) (-1 + p1 + p2)^2) (1 - p1) p1(-128 (-(-1 + p1) p1)^(3/2) (-1 + p2)^2 p2^2 + (384 (-1 + p1)^3 p1^3)/Sqrt[1/(p2 - p2^2)] + 128 Sqrt[-(-1 + p1) p1] (-1 + p2)^3 p2^3 (-3 + 2 Sqrt[((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1)]) + 128 Sqrt[1/(p1 - p1^2)] (3 (-1 + p1) p1 (-1 + p2)^3 p2^3 - (-1 + p2)^4 p2^4 + (2 (-(-1 + p2) p2)^(7/2))/Sqrt[1/(p1 -p1^2)] + ((-1 + p2)^4 p2^4)/(((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1))^(3/2) + 3 (-1 + p1)^4 p1^4 Sqrt[((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1)] - 6 (-1 + p1)^4 p1^4 (((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1))^(3/2)) +4 (1 - p1) p1 (-128 (-(-1 + p2) p2)^(5/2) - 96/(1/(p2 - p2^2))^(5/2)) + 256 (-1 + p1)^2 p1^2 ((-(-1 + p2) p2)^(3/2) + 3/(1/(p2 - p2^2))^(3/2))) == 0 /. p1 -> p1[p2]
```

and attempt to setup an initial condition so that I can then use NDSolveValue. However, something goes wrong. The following initial condition should output {p1 -> 0.882142} (or should it?). It seems to do nothing.

```
p11 = p1[0.75] /. FindRoot[eqn /. p2 -> .75, {p1[.75], .75}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see where you have `p1` defined as a function that would take a value. MMa naturally doesn't know what `p1[.75]` is.

Comment: @BillWatts isn't that what p1 -> p1[p2] does? (Perhaps an obvious newbie question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr = ((1 - 
        p1) p1 (-128 ((1 - p1) p1)^(3/2) (-1 + 
            p2)^2 p2^2 + (384 (-1 + p1)^3 p1^3)/Sqrt[1/(p2 - p2^2)] + 
        128 Sqrt[(1 - p1) p1] (-1 + p2)^3 p2^3 (-3 + 
           2 Sqrt[((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1)]) + 
        128 Sqrt[1/(p1 - 
             p1^2)] (3 (-1 + 
              p1) p1 (-1 + p2)^3 p2^3 - (-1 + 
               p2)^4 p2^4 + (2 ((1 - p2) p2)^(7/2))/
            Sqrt[1/(p1 - 
                p1^2)] + ((-1 + 
                 p2)^4 p2^4)/(((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1))^(3/2) + 
           3 (-1 + p1)^4 p1^4 Sqrt[((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1)] - 
           6 (-1 + p1)^4 p1^4 (((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1))^(3/2)) + 
        4 (1 - p1) p1 (-128 ((1 - p2) p2)^(5/2) - 96/(1/(p2 - p2^2))^(5/2)) + 
        256 (-1 + p1)^2 p1^2 (((1 - p2) p2)^(3/2) + 
           3/(1/(p2 - p2^2))^(3/2))))/(64 (p1 - p2)^2 ((1 - p2) p2)^(3/
         2) (-1 + p1 + p2)^2) // Simplify;
```

The domain over which `expr` is real is given by [`FunctionDomain`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain.html)

```
fd = FunctionDomain[expr, {p1, p2}]

(* 0 < p1 < 1 && 0 < p2 < 1 && p1 - p2 != 0 && p1 + p2 != 1 *)
```

Simplifying `expr` within the specified domain

```
expr2 = expr // FullSimplify[#, fd] &;
```

The effect of the simplification is significant

```
LeafCount /@ {expr, expr2}

(* {335, 184} *)
```

Since you are interested in `expr2 == 0`, it is equivalent to `Numerator@expr2 == 0`

```
LeafCount[Numerator@expr2]

(* 166 *)
```

The simplified form plots more efficiently and precisely

```
ContourPlot[Numerator@expr2 == 0, {p1, 0, 1}, {p2, 0, 1},
  Exclusions -> {p1 == p2, p1 + p2 == 1},
  MaxRecursion -> 5,
  FrameLabel -> {p1, p2}] // Quiet
```

[image]

```
**EDIT:**

Clear["Global`*"]

expr[p1_, p2_] = ((1 - 
       p1) p1 (-128 (-(-1 + p1) p1)^(3/2) (-1 + 
           p2)^2 p2^2 + (384 (-1 + p1)^3 p1^3)/Sqrt[1/(p2 - p2^2)] + 
       128 Sqrt[-(-1 + p1) p1] (-1 + p2)^3 p2^3 (-3 + 
          2 Sqrt[((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1)]) + 
       128 Sqrt[1/(p1 - 
            p1^2)] (3 (-1 + 
             p1) p1 (-1 + p2)^3 p2^3 - (-1 + 
              p2)^4 p2^4 + (2 (-(-1 + p2) p2)^(7/2))/
           Sqrt[1/(p1 - 
               p1^2)] + ((-1 + p2)^4 p2^4)/(((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1))^(3/
              2) + 3 (-1 + p1)^4 p1^4 Sqrt[((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1)] - 
          6 (-1 + p1)^4 p1^4 (((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1))^(3/2)) + 
       4 (1 - p1) p1 (-128 (-(-1 + p2) p2)^(5/2) - 
          96/(1/(p2 - p2^2))^(5/2)) + 
       256 (-1 + p1)^2 p1^2 ((-(-1 + p2) p2)^(3/2) + 
          3/(1/(p2 - p2^2))^(3/2))))/(64 (p1 - p2)^2 (-(-1 + p2) p2)^(3/
        2) (-1 + p1 + p2)^2);

expr2[p1_, p2_] = 
  FullSimplify[expr[p1, p2], FunctionDomain[expr[p1, p2], {p1, p2}]];

LeafCount /@ {expr[p1, p2], expr2[p1, p2]}

(* {341, 184} *)

Manipulate[
 Plot[expr2[p1, p2], {p1, 0.9, 1}], {p2, 0.9001, 0.9999, 0.0001, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
(* *)
```

[image]

Comment: Your tricky simplification without `Exclusions` and increased Workingprecision `ContourPlot[Numerator@expr2 == 0, {p1, 0, 1}, {p2, 0, 1}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 5, FrameLabel -> {p1, p2}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 50] // Quiet` evaluates the contourlines including the points {0,0},{1,0],{0,1},{1,1} !

Comment: Bob Hanlon, as you will notice from my edit, there are solutions closer to p1=1 (or p1 = 0) than what the contour plot show. Can your solution show the needed level of precision?

Comment: See comment by @UlrichNeumann (which you should have already received) above your comment.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question right you want to solve an equation depending on tw0 variables p1,p2.

```
expr[p1,p2]:=((1 - p1) p1 (-128 ((1 - p1) p1)^(3/2) (-1 + p2)^2 p2^2 + (
  384 (-1 + p1)^3 p1^3)/Sqrt[1/(p2 - p2^2)] + 
  128 Sqrt[(1 - p1) p1] (-1 + p2)^3 p2^3 (-3 + 
     2 Sqrt[((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1)]) + 
  128 Sqrt[1/(
   p1 - p1^2)] (3 (-1 + p1) p1 (-1 + p2)^3 p2^3 - (-1 + 
        p2)^4 p2^4 + (2 ((1 - p2) p2)^(7/2))/Sqrt[1/(
     p1 - p1^2)] + ((-1 + 
        p2)^4 p2^4)/(((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1))^(3/2) + 
     3 (-1 + p1)^4 p1^4 Sqrt[((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1)] - 
     6 (-1 + p1)^4 p1^4 (((-1 + p2) p2)/((-1 + p1) p1))^(3/2)) + 
  4 (1 - p1) p1 (-128 ((1 - p2) p2)^(5/2) - 96/(1/(p2 - p2^2))^(
     5/2)) + 256 (-1 + p1)^2 p1^2 (((1 - p2) p2)^(3/2) + 
     3/(1/(p2 - p2^2))^(3/2))))/(64 (p1 - p2)^2 ((1 - p2) p2)^(
3/2) (-1 + p1 + p2)^2)
```

ContourPlot shows the possible solutions p1[p2] in the range `0<p1,p2<1`

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[expr[p1,p2] == 0], {p1, 0, 1}, {p2, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> None,MaxRecursion -> 5, FrameLabel -> {p1, p2},WorkingPrecison->50]
```

[image]

Comment: You understand correctly.

Comment: I am a little surprised by the "gap" at the top-right / bottom-left. Is that due to the level of precision used? If so, how do I amend your code to increase precision?

Comment: Perhaps `WorkingPrecision->..` might help. Alternatively you could evaluate the contourline using NDSolve!